# How to diagnose intermittently slow PHP to MySQL connection speeds on local network?

Tags: php, mysql, macos

Since upgrading to OS X Lion, I have noticed intermittent 6-10 second lags when establishing a connection from PHP 5.3 to a MySQL database on my local network. None of the other developers are experiencing this problem, and neither was I prior to updating.

I have profiled the problem and discovered that the entire lag occurs in `PDO::__construct()`. I have no idea how else I can try to debug this issue - where do I even begin?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you connect to mysql with the ugly `mysql_*` functions? What about directly opening a socket to the server? Do you still experience the lag?

Comment: I experience it when using phpmyadmin as well, which seems to use the `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*` functions depending on the config. I think I have it set to `mysqli_` at the moment. I'll try it with `mysql_` and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have MySQL experience for 15 years and any sort of delays when connecting till now were 100% DNS related issues. Both client and server try to resolve names, possibly forward and reverse. If something is wrong in DNS setup, question goes out and never gets responded. Therefore delay until timeout occurs and next best option is taken.
I would recommend write both sides IP addresses written into /etc/hosts with names to make sure DNS problems are opted out.

Comment: I thought this might be the case but I tried connecting directly to the IP instead of the DNS name and still experienced it, however I have not yet tried doing this since setting `skip-name-resolve` in `my.cnf` on the server. I'll give it another go and report back.

Comment: Connecting to IP does not resolve reverse lookup problems! And of course something else can be always broken in network - duplicate IP, bad ethernet connector with 90% packet loss etc. But if everything else works perfect then I vote for some sort of DNS problem, possibly on server side.

Comment: That may be the case, but the combination of connecting directly to the IP address and `skip-name-resolve` seems to have ameliorated the lag problem for the time being, which will buy me the time I need to worry about the underlying DNS issue later. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I will accept, just as soon as I've spent enough time with it to make sure the problem is well and truly gone.

Comment: @Shabbyrobe Thanks :) I hope it will for my problem.